# Unity + Firebase: is it possible to append data to a keys value, or do I have to retrieve keys data every time?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm a bit worried that I will reach the free data limits of Firebase in a student project. 
Basically my question is:
is it possible to append to the end of the string instead of retrieving key and value, appending and uploading again.
What I want to achieve:
I have to create statistics of user right/wrong answers for particular questions.
I want to have a kvp:
answers: 1r/5w/3r
Where number is the number of users guesses and r/w means right wrong. Whenever the guessing session ends I want to add /numberOfGuesses+RightOrWrongAnswer and the end.

I'm using Unity 2018.

Thank you in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your game is architected or how many people are playing, but I'd be surprised if you hit your free limit on a student project ([you can store 1GB and download 10GB](https://firebase.google.com/pricing)). That string is 8 bytes, let's assume worst case scenario: as a UTF32 string, that would be 32 bytes of data - you'd have to pull that down 312 million times to hit a cap (there'll be some overhead, but I can't imagine it being a hugely impactful). If you're afraid of being charged, you can opt to not have a credit card on file to be doubly sure you stay on a student budget.

If you want to reduce the amount of reading/writing though, I might suggest that instead of:
`key: <value_string>` (so, instead of `session_id: "1r/5w/3r"`)

you structure more like:

```
key:
 - wrong: 5
 - right: 3
```

So have two more values nested under your key. One for all the wrong answers, just an incrementing integer. Then one for all the right answers: just an incrementing integer.

The mechanism to "append" would be a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data#save_data_as_transactions), and you should use these whether you're mutating a string or counter. Firebase tries to be smart with data usage and offline caching, but you don't get much more control other than that.

If order really matters, you might want to get cleverer. You'll generally want to work with the abstractions Realtime Database gives you though to maximize any inherent optimizations (it likes to think in terms of JSON documents, so think about your data layout similarly). This may not be as data optimal, but you may want to consider instead using a ledger of some kind (perhaps using [ServerValue.Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/server-value) to record a single right or wrong answer, and having a [cloud function listening](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) to sum up the results in the background after a game - this would be especially useful if you plan on having a lot of users trying to write the same key at the same time).